# Converting a table column into table rows using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi,

Any idea how to convert column into rows?

Table looks like this:

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+---------+
| id |  name  | morning | afternoon | evening |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+---------+
|  1 | apple  |       1 |         2 |       1 |
|  2 | banana |       2 |         2 |       1 |
|  3 | orange |       1 |         2 |       3 |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

Result should look like this:

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----+
| id |  name  |    day    | no. |
+----+--------+-----------+-----+
|  1 | apple  | morning   |   1 |
|  1 | apple  | afternoon |   2 |
|  1 | apple  | evening   |   1 |
|  2 | banana | morning   |   2 |
|  2 | banana | afternoon |   2 |
|  2 | banana | evening   |   1 |
|  3 | orange | morning   |   1 |
|  3 | orange | afternoon |   2 |
|  3 | orange | evening   |   3 |
+----+--------+-----------+-----+
```

Comment: 3 UNION ALL queries can be used for this.

Comment: hi do you have any idea how to populate the value?  I succeeded except that value was not populated. It gave only the id, name and day.

Comment: Ok added an answer !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing union all will do the trick in the selection, however you wanted the data to be displayed using the order name so you can use an outer select statement and subquery to select data using union all something as

```
select
id,name,day,no
from
(
select id , name , 'morning' as day,morning as no from test
union all
select id , name , 'afternoon' as day,afternoon as no from test
union all
select id , name , 'evening' as day,evening as no from test
)x
order by name
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e5635/2)**

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT id,NAME,morning AS NO ,'morning'  AS DAY FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT id,NAME,afternoon NO,'afternoon' AS DAY FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT id,NAME,evening AS NO , 'evening' AS DAY FROM tablename
ORDER BY id
```